# Perl. Connection speed checking

Tags: perl

I'm new in perl and I have a function that checks whether url available or not.
I need also to measure a speed of connection in that func.
Can anybody tell me how to do this?

```
sub CheckLink
{
    syslog('info', "Checking link state");
    $last_check = time;
    syslog('err', "Impossible to check link: OpenVPN have not connected yet") and return 1 unless $state eq 'online';
    my $http = HTTP::Lite->new;
    $http->local_addr($loc_ip);
    my $req = $http->request(CHECK_URL_1);
    unless ($req) {
        syslog('err', "Link check WARN: Unable to fetch CHECK_URL_1 ".CHECK_URL_1);
        $req = $http->request(CHECK_URL_2);
    }
    syslog('info', "Link check is succesful") and return 1 if $req;
    syslog('err', "Link check FAILED: Unable to fetch CHECK_URL_2 ".CHECK_URL_2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use core module [Time::HiRes](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html) for very precise timing.

Comment: when you speed of the connection do you mean the actual transfer speed like 4Mb/s? or you mean you just want to know how quick it is, I.E the time it takes to fetch the URL?

Comment: I mean I need to ensure whether the speed is higher then the exact value. (for example variable min_speed = 500kb/s)

Comment: you mean overall speed or packet by packet?

Comment: I mean overall speed

Comment: To determine the average speed you need to divide the overall size of the response content by the number of seconds it took to download. Of course you need to download something that is at least 64kByte (that's 500kbit). If that downloads in less than a second, you have more than 500kb/s. If you download something smaller, you cannot guarantee the minimum speed.